# DIP switches on RobotDyn Uno+WiFi

Tags: esp8266

There are theses 8 small pins on the Uno+WiFi board. Can someone please give me a detailed table or something on the settings of these 8 DIP switches?

I'm sorry if this question has already been answered somewhere else but I am bad at looking for stuff online.

Thanks

Comment: but the table is on the link you provided in previous question. CH340 is USB converter for connection to computer. https://robotdyn.com/uno-wifi-r3-atmega328p-esp8266-32mb-flash-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much I am sorry for the inconvenience caused here

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 major chips on the board. Atmega 328, esp8266 and the USB converter CH340. Every device has one RX and one TX pin. But you need sometimes connect the Atmega to esp8266, sometimes connect the Atmega to computer over USB and sometimes connect the esp8266 to computer. The first 6 switches are in pairs (RX and TX) for connecting two of the 3 devices.

- 1,2 ON all others OFF connect esp8266 to Atmega. no connection to
  computer.
- 3,4 ON all others OFF connects Atmega to computer over USB. no
  connection to esp8266
- 5,6 ON all others OFF connects esp8266 to computer over USB. no
  connection to Atmega

The switch 7 sets io 0 of esp8266 LOW which puts esp8266 to flashing mode at reboot. So you turn it ON with connection of esp8266 to USB (computer) to upload sketch to esp8266.